# Serverless .getObjectTagging is not a function

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am trying to get a tag from an s3 object in an AWS lambda function via the Serverless framework, but I am running into errors.

This works without the tagging:

```
const file = await s3
    .getObject({
            Bucket: bucketName,
            Key: fileName,
     })
    .promise();
```

However when I replace `.getObject` with `getObjectTagging` like this...

```
let myTags = [];

const file = await s3
        .getObjectTagging(
                {
                     Bucket: bucketName,
                     Key: fileName,
                 },
                 function (err, data) {
                    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
                    else myTags = data.TagSet
                 }
        )
        .promise();
```

It fails with what appears to be an empty array in the cloudlogs.

I have tried to use both `.getObject` and `getObjectLogging` together but this also fails with...

`s3.getObject(...).getObjectTagging is not a function`

Can anyone please help with what I am doing wrong. I read somewhere it might be permissions, but I have the permissions set as the following in the `serverless.yaml`

```
iamRoleStatements:
  - Effect: Allow
    Action: "*"
    Resource: "*"
```